# Automate TexnicCenter Build Process

Tags: bibtex, biber, automation, texniccenter

For my current project to get everything right, I need the following steps :

1. Clean Project
2. Build Output
3. Bibtex
4. Build Output

Is there some possibility to get this 4 steps automated or scripted somehow?

Comment: Well, many editors will allow you to configure the build steps, so you can go through the whole process in one "command". You also have `latexmk` or `arara` which will be independent of your particular editor. Very likely there are questions on this site addressing each of these possibilities (and perhaps others).

Comment: See [here](http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html#manual-configuration) for general instructions for your particular editor. Unfortunately, I cannot be specific, for I have no access or experience with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: The only time I clean project is when I get a fatal error from an aux file, or after a project is complete.  Bibtex and Makeindex can be automated using Project->Properties, but the build step is not repeated.